# ./create: No such file or directory error in terminal window

Tags: ios, cordova, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am very new to iPhone development and I am looking to work with the PhoneGap framework to create iPhone apps. I installed Phonegap on Mac OS X Lion. I got this error in the terminal window for `./create <project_folder_path> <bundle_id> <project_name>`:

```
 ./create: No such file or directory
```

I have searched Google to solve this error, but I can't find any idea from there. Could you please help me solve this issue and run the project? Thanks in advance. Looking forward to your answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably need to check your current directory with the `pwd` command, which is what the `.` is shorthand for. The `create` executable sits in the Cordova `bin` directory, not your project directory.

For example, [this site](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_command-line_index.md.html#Command-Line%20Usage_ios) shows the required command line to be (spread across multiple lines for readability):

```
./path/to/cordova-ios/bin/create
    /path/to/my_new_cordova_project
    com.example.cordova_project_name
    CordovaProjectName
```

In other words, `create` is separate from your project.

The solution is probably to fully specify the path name of `create`.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me with PhoneGap 2.5. You just have to make sure the path to Phonegap iOS bin is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
./path/to/cordova-ios/bin ./create
~/<project_folder_path> <bundle_id> <project_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

Download cordova-3.0.0 and put the folder in your document folder. Expand cordova-ios.zip inside.

Create a folder CordovaTestProject inside your document folder.

Then, open the terminal and try :

```
./Documents/cordova-3.0.0/cordova-ios/bin/create /Users/<username>/Documents/CordovaXY/HelloWorld org.apache.cordova.HelloWorld HelloWorld
```

replace <username> by your username. You can get it with pwd in terminal. In terminal, type "pwd" and you will get your username

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are inside \phonegap-2.7.0\lib\ios\bin before entering `./create` command. Refer the [Blog Tutorial](http://mythoughtsandexperiments.blogspot.in/2013/12/how-to-install-phonegap-in-mac-and.html) for a simple and straight forward explanation of PhoneGap instalation in Mac for iOS and creating a new project.